# OpenFileDialog auto sort the files order

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I'm using vb.net to develop an application which allows the user to choose multiple files from an OpenFileDialog

my problem now is, the OpenFileDialog won't read the file names according to the order I have selected.

For example the order I've selected to file is - PDF3, PDF1, PDF2

but every time when I read through each of the variable in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames, it was sorted into - PDF1 , PDF2, PDF3 instead.

Help please? I could really mean a lot to me..

Comment: I don't think the dialog allows that. It doesn't keep track of the order in which the user selected items. You might be able to inherit from the OpenFileDialog to create a new version that does. Let me see if I can do that.

Comment: Or you could just make them select the files individually if the order is that important. Don't allow milti-select.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the suggestion but it would be very troublesome if the user has a lot of files to choose

Comment: @MichaelZ., The `OpenFielDialog` class is declared `NotInheritable`.  You'd probably have to create you're class that wrapped the underlying Win32 dialogue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks. I didn't even begin trying a solution and I wasn't aware it was marked not inheritable. That saves me time because I'm not going that far with an answer. OP could maybe have the users sort afterwards in a list box.

Comment: It really doesn't seem that difficult to create this dialog from scratch using all managed code. Could be made a lot better too.

Answer (score 1):

I figured you could monitor messages with wndproc, and yes, someone already put it together. Check out this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) link

Looks like you will be able to handle events. Look at `EventFileNameChanged`, which should be raised when the user clicks a file. You can keep track of file names clicked, which should give you your order.

Comment: Good solution. You'd have to keep track if a file was selected a second time because that unselects it. All in all it sounds too difficult for what it's worth.@Gabriel B S M `TreeView` idea sounds like a better idea than using `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Once the user clicks ok you get all the selected files. You can check them against your tracking array. If you deselect it won't end up in the selected files anyway.

Answer (score 1):

OpenFileDialog isn't really designed to it, so it's gonna be problematic to use it this way.

I have two suggestions:

1. Don't try to process the files in the order they were selected (I don't know why you are trying to achive, so I don't know if you can just give up this idea)
2. Use an `TreeView` to load the name of the files, so the user can select files through the `TreeView`, which makes it a lot easier to keep track of the order they were selected.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I like the idea of a `TreeView` if you really must keep track of the order. This could also give the user the ability to rearrange before submitting. If keeping track of it with `OpenFileDialog` even the user would have to start over if his ordering messed up. The `TreeView` solves that.